# Metro IE10: How to detect if we can use setHomePage()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

Clients wants to display link to set their page as a homepage (I know it is so 1999) on browsers where this feature is available, i.e. basically on IE only.

Since I wanted to do it proper and future-proof way, I came up with this function that runs once page is loaded. The idea is that if, say, IE11 or IE12 stops supporting it, my code will work just fine.

```
function detectSetHomePage() {
    document.body.style.behavior="url(#default#homepage)";

    if (typeof document.body.setHomePage !== "undefined") {
        $(".makeHomepage").removeClass("hidden");
        $(".makeHomepage").on("click", function() {
            document.body.setHomePage(location.href);
        });
    }
}
```

Link shows up as expected on all IE including 10, does not show up on all other browsers.

The only problem is Metro IE10. "Make homepage" link is here, but it does not work. Nothing happens when you click on it.

So how do I modify my "if" statement to make link disappear on Metro IE10?

Comment: When I get home (if no one else has answered yet) I'll play with it but that is odd... it does make sense though, Metro doesn't have a homepage setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting very strange results with IE10 in both Desktop and Metro views as well as on my IE9.

Before setting the behavior:

```
>> document.body.setHomePage
   undefined
>> typeof document.body.setHomePage
   "undefined"
```

Then different if first adding the behavior:

```
>> document.body.style.behavior="url(#default#homepage)"
   "url(#default#homepage)" 
>> document.body.setHomePage
   undefined
>> typeof document.body.setHomePage
   "unknown"
```

There are clearly problems with this methodology for feature detection. I'd recommend simply [having a page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/services/hp/index.html) that shows users how to make the page a homepage or find another way to target below IE9.

**EDIT**

I did some more searching around and there just doesn't seem to be enough difference between Metro and Desktop to differentiate them. The best recommendation I can give is still to either [link to a page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/services/hp/index.html) with steps for a user to make it the home page or to target ActiveX.

Since Metro will never allow ActiveX it will always be excluded, but you will also exclude any desktop versions that have it manually disabled. At least it will never present a broken feature to the client.

Comment: Basically "unknown" is MS’s answer if you try to test or access something that’s not a true part of the JScript engine.

Comment: Since setHomePage() is not a part of JS, but rather is MS invention, that is how am I testing whether I can use it. Works like charm on all IEs below IE10 and on IE10 desktop. IE10 Metro is the only problem - still returns "unknown", yet does not work since there are no home pages.

Comment: Edited answer, not too great though.

Comment: So I ended up doing that: if ( typeof document.body.setHomePage !== "undefined" && isActivexEnabled() )

Comment: Ugly but does not give false positives